# My Textured object isn't showing up in the rendered view :S

Tags: modeling, rendering

[image: Image showing problem :/]

I am new to blender but I've looked all over for a solution and haven't found one, sorry to waste your time but it there a reason my model isn't showing up I've tried and untextured cube and that shows up in the rendered view. I've also tried "In object mode press W -> clear all restricted render." from someone else's similar problem which didn't work.

Comment: yeah [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5KuTkTVeODVSS1ta3piMUIwMlk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: do you need the texture file too??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your object,click `Shift+Ctrl+A` or `ctrl+A` and then select make duplicates real.
[image]

And then it will show up in renders:

[image]

Comment: It would be useful to mention that this was caused by [dupliframes](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/duplication/dupliframes.html) option set to *Frames*.